# Sum of duration between each rows with regards to 2 field in PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duration

I have a set of datas in terms of timestamp, model and mode
The mode comes in 4 different mode denote as (0,2,4,8)

```
Index  Model Timestamp              Mode
1      x  2016-06-26 09:51:24.279   0
2      x  2016-06-26 09:51:26.282   0
3      x  2016-06-26 09:51:28.279   0
4      x  2016-06-26 09:51:30.279   0
5      y  2016-06-26 09:51:32.279   2
6      y  2016-06-26 09:51:34.279   2
7      x  2016-06-26 09:51:36.278   2
8      x  2016-06-26 09:51:38.279   0
9      x  2016-06-26 09:51:40.279   0
10     y  2016-06-26 09:51:42.280   0
11     x  2016-06-26 09:51:44.279   2
12     x  2016-06-26 09:51:46.279   0
13     x  2016-06-26 09:51:48.279   2
14     x  2016-06-26 09:51:50.281   0
15     y  2016-06-26 09:51:52.279   2
16     y  2016-06-26 09:51:54.279   2
17     x  2016-06-26 09:51:56.281   0
18     x  2016-06-26 09:51:58.279   0
19     x  2016-06-26 09:52:00.279   0
```

I will want to look for the time difference in their mode(mapped to the model). So if it transits from mode 0 to 2, at the 1st mode 2 should calculate 0, it should calculate the duration difference as shown below

```
Index  Model Timestamp              Mode  Diff
1      x  2016-06-26 09:51:24.279   0     0
2      x  2016-06-26 09:51:26.282   0     2.002
3      x  2016-06-26 09:51:28.279   0     1.998
4      x  2016-06-26 09:51:30.279   0     2
5      y  2016-06-26 09:51:32.279   2     0
6      y  2016-06-26 09:51:34.279   2     2
7      x  2016-06-26 09:51:36.278   2     0
8      x  2016-06-26 09:51:38.279   0     0
9      x  2016-06-26 09:51:40.279   0     2
10     y  2016-06-26 09:51:42.280   0     0
11     x  2016-06-26 09:51:44.279   2     0
12     x  2016-06-26 09:51:46.279   0     0
13     x  2016-06-26 09:51:48.279   2     0
14     x  2016-06-26 09:51:50.281   0     0
15     y  2016-06-26 09:51:52.279   2     0
16     y  2016-06-26 09:51:54.279   2     2
17     x  2016-06-26 09:51:56.281   0     6
18     x  2016-06-26 09:51:58.279   0     1.998
19     x  2016-06-26 09:52:00.279   0     2
```

As of now, I do a sort (group time and mode) in mode then find the difference which is correct. I am unable to get the 0 when it transits.

Please advice!

```
tdm = mydataset.groupby(["Model","Drive Mode"])["timestamp"]
mydataset["DM-Diff"] = tdm.diff().fillna(0) / pd.datetools.timedelta(seconds = 1)
mydataset = mydataset[mydataset["DM-Diff"] < 180]
mydataset = mydataset[mydataset["DM-Diff"] > -1]#hardcoding with range so that it will not include other mode value
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
In [42]: breaks = df['Mode'].ne(df['Mode'].shift()).cumsum()

In [43]: (df.groupby(breaks)['Timestamp'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 's')).fillna(0)
Out[43]:
0     0.000
1     2.003
2     1.997
3     2.000
4     0.000
5     2.000
6     1.999
7     0.000
8     2.000
9     2.001
10    0.000
11    0.000
12    0.000
13    0.000
14    0.000
15    2.000
16    0.000
17    1.998
18    2.000
Name: Timestamp, dtype: float64
```

---

Details

```
In [44]: breaks
Out[44]:
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     3
8     3
9     3
10    4
11    5
12    6
13    7
14    8
15    8
16    9
17    9
18    9
Name: Mode, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your ans, Can i check with you on  " breaks = df['Mode'].ne(df['Mode'].shift()).cumsum()". What does this line actually means?

Comment: Hi @Zero Dont mind me, i've updated the questions. Do take a look and thank you for your reply!